# Как сделать фиксированные пробелы для детского издания в InDesign, чтобы не возникало "коридоров"?

Tags: вёрстка, adobe, гост

Я верстаю детское издание 6+ (2-я возрастная категория). ГОСТ устанавливает норму пробела с кегль шрифта. В качестве пробела установил круглую шпацию, но визуально пробелы получаются слишком большими. Как избежать этой проблемы?

Пример ниже
[image: верстка]

Comment: Нормальные пробелы у вас только между тире и словами, всё остальное в разнобой, происходит это из-за выравнивания текста во всю страницу. Такое выравнивание растягивает пробелы.

Comment: Но я не могу убрать выравнивание по ширине, это же книга. Может, можно как-то иначе настроить пробелы?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, только играться с переносами слов.